# Comparing each word from a sentence entered by user with another text (android/java)

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, comparator

basically I'm trying to write a program where the program will capture user input and compare with the contents of an already defined array. If user inputs correctly, then he'll be given a point for each word. If not, number of lives decrease. I have two issues:

1) found seems to resolving in being false even when "Hello my name is" is typed in because every time i click on the score button, i get a decrease in life for every word i type in.

2) how do i implement my code in a way where the user will need to type it in order to get a point instead of typing "my Hello is name" as that would be correct? as there is a match of elements in each array.

My code is:

```
Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_input);
String[] user_text;
String[] text = {"Hello, my, name, is"};

public void onClick(View v) {

    int points = 0;
    int lives = 4;
    String s = editText.getText().toString();
    user_text = s.split("\\s+");

    for (int i = 0; i < user_text.length; i++) {

        user_text[i] = user_text[i].replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");

        }
    for (int i = 0; i < user_text.length; i++) {

        boolean found = false;

    for (int j = 0; j < text.length; j++) {

        if ((user_text[i].equals(text[j]))) {
              found = true;
              break;
        }

        if (found) {
              points++;
       } 

       else {
              lives--;
       }

    }
      score_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

      score_view.setText("score: " + points + "\n lives: " + lives );


 }
 });
```

Comment: `[^\\w]` is the long way to say `\\W`, and your `text` field is an array of 1 value, not 4.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you are trying to match two arrays.
Here is your piece of code modified to achieve array matching.

```
boolean found = true;
for (int i = 0; i < user_text.length && i<text.length; i++) {
    if (!(user_text[i].equals(text[i]))) {
        found = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (found) {
    points++;
} 
else {
    lives--;
}
```

Comment: Also, `found` should be false if arrays have different length.